# Does installing kubernetes affect the docker on which the current machine is running?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a server running the docker container, I want him to join the existing kubernetes cluster and not affect the container that is currently running.

Because it is a production environment, I have not tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think k8s implementation should not impact existing docker containers within the same compute environment. As @coderanger mentioned in his answer, `kubelet`manages garbage collection [mechanism](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/) in order to keep system utilization on appropriate level and reduce amount of unused containers by adjusting the specific thresholds.

However, as per official k8s documentation, `kubelet` eviction method should not affect any containers which are not managed by k8s itself.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly yes, running containers should be unaffected but the kubelet might try to clean up unused images.

Comment: Does it? Do you have a documentation link that explains that? Just curious